# ILOG variable set equivalent in Drools

Tags: drools, ilog, jrules

I am trying to migrate an existing ILOG JRules based application to Drools based project. In ILOG we have [local variables](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/brjrules/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/ilog.rules.jrules.doc/Content/Business_Rules/Documentation/_pubskel/JRules/ps_JRules_Global1204.html) (and variable set) which can be used to calculate and store intermediate values within rules (formulas).

Is there an equivalent of local variables in Drools? I know we have [Globals in Drools](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html/ch05.html#d0e3313) but the documentation suggest to use Globals only as read only constants and to pass data between Java calling class to rules:

> It is strongly discouraged to set or change a global value from inside
>   your rules. We recommend to you always set the value from your
>   application using the working memory interface.

One approach would be to write a custom java class `Variable` and declare all variables within it and use it in drools rules. But that would need a java code change everytime we want to add a new variable.

Is there any feasible method of defining and using variables in Drools which can be defined and altered within rules?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong in using globals to keep some kind of calculation or state between your rules. I think what Drools' documentation is trying to say (in a very complicated and unclear way) is that you should never use globals in the RHS of the rules because Drools doesn't know when the value of a global changes. If you do use globals in your constraints, then make sure you never change their values. Having saud that, I think that using globals in the RHS of your rules is harmless. 
If you are not comfortable with this idea, then you could also insert your "Calculation" object as a fact in your session. Rules can match against this fact, bind a variable to it and then interact with it in the RHS.

Hope it helps,